# pandas dataframe from_dict - Set column name for key, and column name for key-value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
my_keys = {'a':10, 'b':3, 'c':23}
```

I turn it into a Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_keys)
```

It outputs the `df` as below

```
     a     b    c
0    10    3    23
```

How can I get it to look like below:

```
Col1    Col2
a        10
b         3
c        23
```

I've tried orient=index but I still can't get column names?

Comment: if that is so then I might have read the date/time of posting of this question wrong. Please ignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_keys.items()), columns=['col1','col2'])
```

Or convert keys and values to separate lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list(my_keys.keys()),'col2':list(my_keys.values())})
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    a    10
1    b     3
2    c    23
```

Your solution should be changed by `orient='index'` and `columns`, but then is necessary add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and 
[`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_keys, orient='index', columns=['col2'])
        .rename_axis('col1')
        .reset_index())
```

Comment: Nice one! that worked. I thought I had to use 'from_dict' :/

Comment: How would I disable the index?

Comment: @AriVictor - If write to file? Then `df.to_csv(file, index=False)`, if need print output `print (df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: You're a legend.